# Simplificar código que alterna divs estilo GIF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, revisión-de-código

Tengo este código que alterna divs en función de su ID en un intervalo de tiempo dado al estilo GIF.

Me gustaría saber si hay un modo de simplificar el código y hacerlo en función de una clase o de algún modo más simple porque si tengo 20 palabras que quiero que cambien se hará más pesado el documento y quiero evitarlo.

```js
jQuery(function () {
    var $els = $('div[id^=picturez7]'),
        i = 0,
        len = $els.length;

    $els.slice(1).hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
            i = (i + 1) % len
            $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
        })
    }, 600)
})
jQuery(function () {
    var $els = $('div[id^=pictureS7]'),
        i = 0,
        len = $els.length;

    $els.slice(1).hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
            i = (i + 1) % len
            $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
        })
    }, 600)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=pictureS7>
  DALES
  </div>
<div id=pictureS72>
  GASOLINA
  </div>
<div id=pictureS73>
 A ELLAS LES GUSTA
  </div>
<div id=pictureS73>
 LA GASOLINA
  </div>
<div id=pictureS7>
  HOLA
  </div>
<div id=picturez72>
  QUE TAL
  </div>
<div id=picturez73>
  SOY EL CHICO DE LAS POESÍAS
  </div>
<div id=picturez73>
  TU FIEL ADMIRADOR
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada los Id deben ser unicos, no se puede repetir. Creo que lo que buscas es algo como esto:

```
function GIf(Selector) {
    var $els = $(Selector),
        i = 0,
        len = $els.length;

    $els.slice(1).hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
            i = (i + 1) % len
            $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
        })
    }, 600)
 };

 GIf('div[class^="picturez7"]');
 GIf('div[class^="pictureS7"]');
```

Y el HTML seria algo como esto:

```
<div class=pictureS7>
  DALES
  </div>
<div class=pictureS72>
  GASOLINA
  </div>
<div class=pictureS73>
 A ELLAS LES GUSTA
  </div>
<div class=pictureS73>
 LA GASOLINA
  </div>
<div class=pictureS7>
  HOLA
  </div>
<div class=picturez72>
  QUE TAL
  </div>
<div class=picturez73>
  SOY EL CHICO DE LAS POESÍAS
  </div>
<div class=picturez73>
  TU FIEL ADMIRADOR
  </div>
```

[Demo en vivo.](https://jsfiddle.net/gr6t2d6o/) Acá tan solo pasar un selector, llamaras el efecto que deseas.

Comment: Es perfecto, lo que buscaba simplemente era un modo de aligerar el código. Gracias por el aporte.

Comment: @IvanSoler De nada para eso estamos.

Comment: Perdona, estoy intentando hacerlo para un <pre> y no me lo permite, hay que variar algo?

Comment: @IvanSoler para un pre es igual pero el selector cambia, mira el ejemplo aca https://jsfiddle.net/hxojagzx/1/ actualizado con pre.

Comment: Continúa sin funcionar, debe haber alguna interacción que desconozco con el resto del código; tendré que mantenerlo así. Gracias.

Comment: @IvanSoler Cuando tengas problemas así, presiona f12 y mira la consola a ver que te sale, y se te puede dar una mejor solución, pero como te mostré en el demo funciona, es algo en tu ambiente de desarrollo. Saludos.